# Christianity never rises. Does the U.S. exist?

Tags: alternate-history, united-states

> In the chain of human events, the birthday of the nation is indissolubly linked with the birthday of the Savior. The Declaration of Independence laid the cornerstone of human government upon the first precepts of Christianity.
>   –John Quincy Adams, *An Oration Delivered Before the Inhabitants of the Town of Newburyport at Their Request on the Sixty-First Anniversary of the Declaration of Independence, July 4, 1837* (Newburyport: Charles Whipple, 1837), pp. 5-6.

---

Does the secession from Britain ever happen? Does Britain happen?

If anything happened, what year would it be? Certainly not 1776 *anno Domini*.

**If Christianity never rises, what happens to the United States?**

Bonus points for explaining the state of Judaism and the influence it has on the world.

Comment: I changed the question, because the birth of Jesus is largely irrelevant. (Many researchers can't find proof of him existing). However, if Christianity never rises, regardless of if Jesus exists, it leads directly into the question you ask.

Comment: @Andon That's valid. It's essentially the same thing, since without Christ there would be no Christianity. Though the answer from (user) sphennings brings up a good point. Proof of Christ is irrelevant. The religion itself is the driver of this.

Comment: With a point of divergence 1700 years before the formation of the United States. It's impossible to predict whether the Unites States would exist or not.

Comment: This is almost certainly too broad. You are asking for a rewriting of most of European history.

Comment: The question seems a bit flawed as it could be argued that a major component of what makes both Britain and the US, the entities we know today, is based on religion.  Altering this religion would fundamentally change what defines these countries.  Are you asking if people would still inhabit these lands, then the answer is definitely.  But changing the religions that both countries were founded upon would arguably make them no longer embody enough characteristics to even be comparable to the current iterations of those countries.

Comment: The driving force behind most of European politics from (?including) the fall of the Roman empire was religion. Changing that changes everything.

Comment: @Andon "Many researchers can't find proof of him existing." What? Explain to me exactly how there is more proof of Alexander the Great or any other 2000 year old person than there is of Jesus? If you don't believe Jesus existed, how could you justify Socrates, Buddha, or Mohammed?

Comment: I'll also add that it has been argued that if Christianity never rose to prominence, then the "dark ages" would have had less of an impact on technological advancement in Europe and thus, expansion to the Americas may have begun much earlier.

Comment: @bhilgert By who? I argue that without Christianity, we would still have slaves. What do you say to that?

Comment: @kingledion Huh? What do Slaves have to do with the Dark Ages? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Ages_(historiography) Also, it can be argued that slavery still exists in many parts of the world today, irrespective of religion and culture.  This includes the US.

Comment: @bhilgert My point is that you can argue a lot of things, and that doesn't mean that they are right. For example, if you argue that slaves still exist in the US, you would be wrong. Your comments saying 'it has been argued' are worse than useless. You aren't making a case yourself, you are just airy stating that you 'feel' something to be true.

Comment: @kingledion ok, here's a source. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contemporary_slavery_in_the_United_States A quick Google search on modern slave trade can yield plenty of citations.  Are you saying that all those articles are wrong? My comments are not 'airy', but rather taking into consideration that some people will state that slavery does not exist, because it is illegal.  Or that from another POV, that without Christianity, slavery would still be legal in the US.  That is an opinion and has no facts behind it.  Can you find a source for your statement that we don't have slaves?

Comment: @bhilgert I am saying that all those articles are wrong. Five minutes clicking on links from the wikipedia page (many of them dead) shows that there are are no official statistics or peer-reviewed claims. Just because you saw it on the internet, doesn't make it true. My statement about Christianity and slavery has as many 'facts' behind it as yours.

Comment: @kingledion regards to proof of Alexander or Socrates. Either is mentioned by eye witness accounts. Alexander for example has statues from the time he was alive. Jesus is only mentioned in holy texts that are severely edited after his death or even just written long after his death. Number of records and quality of the records is the difference.

Comment: @kingledion http://www.jstor.org/stable/23719716?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents, https://www.questia.com/library/journal/1G1-143011615/slave-trade-combating-human-trafficking, http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Peer+reviewed+article+modern+slavery+US.  Can you provide a link that shows that Christianity has had a direct impact on ending slavery, that the religion itself is responsible for ending slavery in all forms in every country?  Also, please provide some proof that slavery is non-existent in modern times.  I believe the tenants of ISIS actually approve and encourage slavery.

Comment: @Mormacil Oh really? Can you find me an original statue (not a Roman copy) that survives from Alexanders' time? In fact, can you find a first person account that survives (not a quotation from a later work)? Turns out, Tacitus, Josephus, and Pliny reference Christ closer in history to His life than any biographers mention Alexander. Futhermore surviving textual evidence of the Gospels exists within 100 years of Christ's death. You can't even find an account _written_ within 100 years of Alexander's death (the oldest is ~60 BC) much less a surviving physical fragment.

Comment: @bhilgert Why do you keep talking about slavery in the US? There is obviously no slavery in the US. The latest thing you link doesn't even claim that. We were talking about you claiming that Christianity caused the Dark Ages to be prolonged.

Answer (score 1):

It could have been the same but with a different religion. In case that Christianity did not develop, another religion would have taken its place, after all Roman religion was weak during the end of the empire.
For example, manicheism might have replaced Christianity during its early stages, or Islam in the latter.

Since United State was colonized by people who was running from religion persecution in England, in your alternate history the founding fathers could be shiites minorities while in England most people are Sunni.

Judaism probably would be the same, because judaism is inherit, hence is more difficult to convert people from other religions to judaism.

Comment: No Christianity probably means no Islam

Comment: @Jacob, I've never heard that before, normally it's referred to as starting around the 7th Century CE.

Comment: @Jacob How did Islam diverge from Judaism before Muhammed founded the religion?